# approx function in R is it random?

Tags: r, function, equation, approximation

I'm using approx function on 2 identical  list :

```
unlist(fp_st_4_main[[1]],fp_st_4_main_extr[[1]])  0.02438017
0.03842975 0.04504132 0.07231405 0.08884298 0.09917355 0.11363636 0.12644628  0.13966942 0.15289256 0.16818182 0.17190083 0.23471074 0.25330579 0.26818182 0.29090909




unlist(fp_st_3_main[[1]],fp_st_3_main_extr[[1]])  [1] 0.02438017 0.03842975 0.04504132 0.07231405 0.08884298 0.09917355 0.11363636 0.12644628  [9] 0.13966942 0.15289256 0.16818182 0.17190083 0.23471074 0.25330579 0.26818182 0.29090909



unlist(tp_st_4_main[[1]],tp_st_4_main_extr[[1]])
0.4625 0.4625 0.4625 0.4625 0.4625 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750




unlist(tp_st_3_main[[1]],tp_st_3_main_extr[[1]])
 [1] 0.4625 0.4625 0.4625 0.4625 0.4625 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750
```

As the list are absolutely the same I'm expecting R to preform the same interpolation on both of them :

```
my_out=seq(0,1,0.01)
intrapulation_my=approx(c(0,fp_st_4_main[[1]],fp_st_4_main_extr[[1]],1),c(0,tp_st_4_main[[1]],tp_st_4_main_extr[[1]],1), method = "linear", xout =my_out )
intrapulation_st_4_main_tp_my=intrapulation_my$y
intrapulation_st_4_main_fp_my=intrapulation_my$x

intrapulation_my=approx(c(0,fp_st_3_main[[1]],fp_st_3_main_extr[[1]],1), c(0,tp_st_3_main[[1]],tp_st_3_main_extr[[1]],1), method = "linear", xout =my_out )
intrapulation_st_3_main_tp_my=intrapulation_my$y
intrapulation_st_3_main_fp_my=intrapulation_my$x
```

But the result Im getting for them is different :

```
intrapulation_st_4_main_tp_my
  [1] 0.0000000 0.1897034 0.3794068 0.4625000 0.4625000 0.4625000 0.4625000 0.4625000 0.4625000
 [10] 0.4751000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000
 [19] 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000
 [28] 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5833557 0.5925469 0.6017382 0.6109294 0.6201206 0.6293119
 [37] 0.6385031 0.6476944 0.6568856 0.6660769 0.6752681 0.6844593 0.6936506 0.7028418 0.7120331
 [46] 0.7212243 0.7304155 0.7396068 0.7487980 0.7579893 0.7671805 0.7763718 0.7855630 0.7947542
 [55] 0.8039455 0.8131367 0.8223280 0.8315192 0.8407105 0.8499017 0.8590929 0.8682842 0.8774754
 [64] 0.8866667 0.8958579 0.9050492 0.9142404 0.9234316 0.9326229 0.9418141 0.9510054 0.9601966
 [73] 0.9693878 0.9785791 0.9877703 0.9969616 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 [82] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 [91] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
[100] 1.0000000 1.0000000




intrapulation_st_3_main_tp_my
  [1] 0.0000000 0.1897034 0.3794068 0.4625000 0.4625000 0.4625000 0.4625000 0.4625000 0.4625000
 [10] 0.4751000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000
 [19] 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000
 [28] 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.5750000 0.6163717 0.6618805 0.7073894 0.7528982 0.7984071 0.8439159
 [37] 0.8894248 0.9349336 0.9804425 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 [46] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 [55] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 [64] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 [73] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 [82] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 [91] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
[100] 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

What I don't understand is how can it be ?
As i understand the interulation works like this :

Given two points (x_1, y_1) and (x_2, y_2), where x_1 < x_2, the equation of the straight line passing through these points can be expressed as:

y=mx+b

where:

```latex
\begin{itemize}
\item $m$ is the slope of the line, given by $m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$
\item $b$ is the y-intercept of the line, given by $b = y_1 - mx_1$
\end{itemize}
```

To perform linear interpolation between two points x_1 and x_2, where x_1 < x < x_2, we can substitute x into the equation of the straight line to estimate the corresponding y value. so it is supposed to return the same values for Y  but it returns me different values , how can that be ?

Comment: It's difficult to work with this data, but if I scrape the numbers from your first code block and then run `approx` on them, I don't get the results you have in your `intrapulation_st_4_main_tp_my`; this could be due to rounding issues. Can you replace your console-output data with the output of `dput`? It is also a little distracting (for me) to work with long-and-barely-different object names, if you do `fp4 <- unlist(fp_st_4_main[[1]],fp_st_4_main_extr[[1]])`, post the output from `dput(fp4)`, then change your `approx` to `approx(c(0, fp4, 1), ...)` (and same for `tp4`), it might help.

Comment: (and the same for `fp3` and `tp3` :-)

Comment: @r2evans thank you , it helped i was also wondering : I have many repeating values in my lists for example :```unlist(c(0,tp_st_4_main[[1]],tp_st_4_main_extr[[1]],1))
 [1] 0.0000 0.4625 0.4625 0.4625 0.4625 0.4625 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 0.5750 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000  1.0000``` the approx function collapses them to a single values for example the values 1.0000 here :```In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values``` is there any way to prevent the collapsing?

Comment: (1) comments are really not good for sample data and code. (2) That isn't from `dput`. (3) I'm not sure, but your `tp4` data is mostly invariant, which is certainly going to affect interpolation.

Comment: I don't see any randomness in [the source](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/approx.R). If you want to change your question to why you get different results, please remove the `random` tag.